# SharePoint 2010 Farm Solution Deployment Error Using Non-admin Accounts

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, visual-studio-2012, solution-deployment, cksdev

I am trying to deploy a farm solution using Visual Studio 2012 on SharePoint 2010. I receive the following error when I try to build or deploy using any admin group accounts other than the Farm Admin account. I strictly followed [this guideline](http://nikpatel.net/2010/11/09/sharepoint-2010-development-environment-and-account-permission-requirements-checklist/) to setup a developer account but I get the same error on the developer account:

> The Project Item "ProjName" cannot be deployed through a Package.

We have no relevant SharePoint Log stored.
The setting is as follows:

- The solution is at Farm scope is being deployed at webapplication level (VS solution settings are: Active Dev: No Activation; Assembly included for GAC through the package settings)
- The solution is a WCF(CKSDev).
- We have one application server and two web front ends (SP Standard edition). We have the latest SharePoint update package installed.

Any suggestions regarding how to overcome this issue is greatly appreciated.

Comment: what is the complete error? http://sharepoint2010developer.blogspot.com/2011/07/error-sandboxed-solution-deploy.html

Comment: The complete error is exactly as above in VS error list. It does not have "a sandbox solution". It is actually a Farm solution.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to resolve such issue by restarting Visual Studuo.